# Choosing a List as VertexWeight for a TreeGraph

Tags: list-manipulation, graphs-and-networks

I would like to map every vertex of my TreeGraph to an List.

```
g=TreeGraph[{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}, {1 \[DirectedEdge] 2, 1 \[DirectedEdge] 3, 
  1 \[DirectedEdge] 4, 1 \[DirectedEdge] 5}, 
 VertexWeight -> {{1}, {4}, {9}, {16}, {25}}]
```

It seems that g is not a valid graph whereas the next one is valid

```
gg=TreeGraph[{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}, {1 \[DirectedEdge] 2, 1 \[DirectedEdge] 3, 
  1 \[DirectedEdge] 4, 1 \[DirectedEdge] 5}, 
 VertexWeight -> {1, 4, 9, 16, 25}]
```

So it seems that we can't use a List as a Weight of a Vertex.

But the [VertexWeight documentation](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/VertexWeight.html) says clearly

> The weight  can be any expression.

So I don't understant why `gg` works well whereas `g` doesn't work.

Best Regards

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 
1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by **answering questions** in your area of expertise. 
2) Read the [faq]!
3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge.
Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)!

Comment: Looks like `List` is treated as an exception for some reason. `VertexWeight -> foo /@ {1,4,16,25,}` works as stated in the docs. As an aside, if you really have to use `List`s as weights, you could use `VertexWeight -> (Defer /@ {{1}, {4}, {9}, {16}, {25}})` .